# Why is Drupal deleting my images?

Tags: 7, media, files

I have images going mysteriously missing from my Drupal site, sometimes several all at once.  There are currently only two people who have access to edit these, myself and a manager in Corporate Communications.  She just alerted me to a half a dozen disappearing all at once, and claims she did not delete them.  I have no reason to doubt her word, and I know I did not delete them.  This started happening months ago, and I had thought I may have fixed it a couple of months ago by deselecting "Delete unused files" in the One-click Upload settings.  Apparently that did not fix the problem.

Why is Drupal eating my content?  How can I stop it?

Comment: How are these images being added? Are you using the Media module with a WYSIWYG editor by any chance?

Comment: Not the Media module, but I am using a WYSIWYG editor with the one-click upload module.

Comment: Actually, though I'm using that module, I just realized the images I've had problems with aren't inside a text area.  They're added with a file upload field.

Comment: Are they being linked from entities other than the ones on which they were originally uploaded?

Comment: If by 'linked' you mean a simple hyperlink, then no, I'm fairly sure they are not.

Comment: Are they appearing in the file_usage table as expected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7439/discussion-between-iconoclast-and-beth)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the One-Click Upload module, but you might want to check the file_usage table after adding an image to see if it's recording a usage. If it's not recording a usage, it's being deleted because on cron run, Drupal automatically deletes files from file_managed that don't have a usage recorded in file_usage.

Drupal does not detect linking from entities other than the one(s) on which a usage was originally recorded. For example, if you added a link to an image in the markup of node 5, but the image was uploaded as an attachment on node 3, the image will disappear when node 3 is deleted, and node 5 will show a broken link.

If this is your problem, you could solve it by using the [File Lock](http://drupal.org/project/file_lock) module to add file usages so they aren't deleted, or you could switch to the Media module, and apply [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/1268116#comment-6988574) that has been committed to the latest dev (and that I personally wrote some tests for) to ensure that a usage is being recorded for files uploaded via WYSIWYG.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411405/uploaded-images-in-drupal-are-being-automatically-deleted.. this worked for me.